# Mongo Vector Search - The heap is empty

Tags: pymongo

What does it mean when `pymongo` raises an exception of type `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure`

Exception is:

```
The heap is empty, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'The heap is empty', 'code': 8, 'codeName': 'UnknownError', '$clusterTime': {'clusterTime': Timestamp(1690967467, 7), 'signature': {'hash': b'....', 'keyId': ....}}, 'operationTime': Timestamp(1690967467, 7)}
```

Is there anything I can change to avoid this exception?

Note:

- the index is active and never thrown this exception with atlas search.
- I am connecting to a secondary instance with read only mode.

It is not clear how to reproduce the error since it happens randomly, if I repeat the request it returns results.

### Update:

Pymongo version: `pymongo==4.1.1`

MongoDB version: `MongoDB 6.0.8 Enterprise`

I connect to Mongo using this URI:

`"mongodb+srv://USER:PASS@DOMAIN/DB_NAME?readPreference=secondary"`

More about vector search here: [How to Do Semantic Search in MongoDB Using Atlas Vector Search](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/atlas/semantic-search-mongodb-atlas-vector-search/)

Comment: I believe `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure` is raised after an error on the server (could be caused by the client though).  I couldn't find _'The heap is empty'_ in the MongoDB server nor `pymongo` source.  What version of `pymongo` are you using?  What is the version of the MongoDB server?  Perhaps showing exactly how you connect _"to a secondary instance with read only mode"_ would be helpful.  BTW, what do you mean by _"Mongo Vector Search"_?

Comment: Perhaps there are more clues in the MongoDB server log.  Any chance you could look at that?  You do have a `Timestamp`.